# InAppPurchase with phonegap 1.4.1

Tags: cordova

InAppPurchase with phonegap 1.4.1 or any phonegap version , please provide help , I got following error.

```
[Switching to process 26511 thread 0x2303]
2012-08-01 08:55:45.189 FlightAttendantAnnouncementsLite[26511:207] Device initialization: DeviceInfo = {"name":"iPhone Simulator","uuid":"4D6664CE-E202-5EFF-8139-97F2021DD185","platform":"iPhone Simulator","gap":"1.4.1","version":"5.0","connection":{"type":"wifi"}};
2012-08-01 08:55:45.218 FlightAttendantAnnouncementsLite[26511:207] PGPlugin class  (pluginName: InAppPurchaseManager) does not exist.
2012-08-01 08:55:45.219 FlightAttendantAnnouncementsLite[26511:207] ERROR: Plugin 'InAppPurchaseManager' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.
2012-08-01 08:55:45.220 FlightAttendantAnnouncementsLite[26511:207] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"InAppPurchaseManager","methodName":"setup","arguments":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should complet your Cordova.plist with key InAppPurchaseManager and it's value InAppPurchaseManager.

Maybe it's different on 1.4.1 version (I work on the 2.0.0)

I work on it since 2 days and got this error. But I can't use it, I hope you'll have more chance than me...